# Converting a dictionary of lists of dictionaries to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, literals

I have the following subsample of dictionary of lists of dictionaries (from a larger dictionary of millions of items):

```
bool_dict = {0: [{0: 4680}, {1: 1185}], 
             1: [{0: 172}, {1: 9}], 
             2: [{0: 149}, {1: 1282}], 
             3: [{0: 20}, {1: 127}], 
             4: [{0: 0}, {1: 0}]}
```

which I converted to a dataframe of the form:

```
          0          1
0  {0: 4680}  {1: 1185}
1   {0: 172}     {1: 9}
2   {0: 149}  {1: 1282}
3    {0: 20}   {1: 127}
4     {0: 0}     {1: 0}
```

by doing the following:

```
test=pd.DataFrame(bool_dict.values(),columns['0','1'],index=bool_dict.keys()).sort_index()
```

The problem is that I only need each cell's value, not the key, in the dataframe. So, the desired output is:

```
       0          1
0      4680       1185
1       172          9
2       149       1282
3        20        127
4         0          0
```

I tried the following:

```
test['0'] = test['0'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

but then I get a key error on what I thought was a dictionary.

To make sure it indeed was a dictionary, I then tried

```
from ast import literal_eval
test['0']=test['0'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

then tried this again

```
test['0'] = test['0'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

with no success (I also tried the key as '0').

UPDATE: to make sure the lambda was the issue, this works just fine:

```
test['0'].head(): 

0    {0: 4680}
1     {0: 247}
2       {0: 0}
3       {0: 0}
4     {0: 104}
```

I could do the hacky thing of a split by the `:` and then remove extraneous stuff, but that just feels wrong for so many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert the inner list into a dictionary then pass it to the DataFrame constructor:

```
bool_dict_flattened = {i: {k:v for d in lst for k,v in d.items()} for i, lst in bool_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bool_dict_flattened, orient='index')
```

Another option is to apply `str` accessor on the columns by using the fact that column names and keys match for each column:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bool_dict, orient='index').apply(lambda x: x.str[x.name])
```

Output:

```
      0     1
0  4680  1185
1   172     9
2   149  1282
3    20   127
4     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each row by first lambda and iterate through each cell in that row with the second lambda and read the values of the dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(bool_dict).T
df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: list(y.values())[0]))
df

      0     1
0  4680  1185
1   172     9
2   149  1282
3    20   127
4     0     0
```